# Where can I find a cannabinoids profile of hemp strains?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

For my web article, I need to find out the content of individual cannabinoids in hemp strains, specifically for Kompolti, Carmagnola and Purple Haze. I mean the content of all the components, not just THC and CBD.

Do you know of any website that provides this information?

Thank you for answer